# Alternate to storing Large number of tables -- MySQL

Tags: mysql

Well, I have been working with large amount of network data. In which I have to filter out some IP address and store their communication with other IP's. But the number of IP's are huge, hundreds of thousands, for which I have to create so many tables. Ultimately I my MySQL access will slow down, everything will slow down. Each table will have few columns, many rows.

My Questions:
Is there a better way to deal with this, I mean storing data of each IP?
Is there something like table of tables?

[Edit]
The reason I am storing in different tables is, I have to keep removing and add entries as time passes by.
Here is the table structure

`CREATE TABLE IP(syn_time datetime, source_ip varchar(18), dest_ip varchar(18));`

I use C++ to access with ODBC connector

Comment: Why do you have to create new physical tables? Do these tables have different structures or is it the same table structure copied over and over and over again? That (creating many tables dynamically) usually indicates something is wrong with the overall design.

Comment: would you put in some SQL DDL statements to show us how you are doing this at the moment, please? It's unclear as to why you would need to store lots of tables - did you mean rows?

Comment: Why must you do it across many tables? Why not store your hundreds of thousands of rows in one table like the rest of us?

Comment: Also, little more information would be helpful.  I.E. how is the data being entered into the MySQL database: PHP, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't DROP/CREATE tables frequently. MySQL is very buggy with doing that, and understandably so--it should only be done once when the database is created on a new machine. It will hurt things like your buffer pool hit ratio, and disk IO will spike out.
- Instead, use InnoDB or xtradb, which means you can delete old rows whilst inserting new ones.
- Store the IP in a column of type `int(10) unsigned` e.g. 192.168.10.50 would be stored as (192 * 2^24) + (168 * 2^16) + (10 * 2^8) + 50 = 3232238130
- Put all the information into 1 table, and just use an `SELECT ... WHERE` on an indexed column

Comment: I liked your way of storing IP address. I will try out some Database engines like innoDB and see what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Creating tables dynamically is almost always a bad idea. The alternative is *normalisation*. I won't go into the academic details of that, but I'll try to explain it in more simple terms.

You can separate relationships between data into three types: one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many. Think about how each bit of data relates to other bits and which type of relationship it has.

- If a data relationship is one-to-one,
  then you can usually just stick it in
  the same row of the same table.
  Occasionally there may be a reason to
  separate it as if it were
  one-to-many, but generally speaking,
  stick it all in the same place.
- If a data relationship is
  one-to-many, it should be referenced
  between two tables by it's primary
  key (you've given each table a
  primary key, right?). The "one" side
  of one-to-many should have a field
  which references the primary key of
  the other table. This field is called
  a foreign key.
- Many-to-many is the most complex
  relationship, and it sounds like you
  have a few of these. You have to
  create a join table. This table will
  contain two foreign key fields, one
  for one table and another for the
  other. For each link between two
  records, you'll add one record to
  your join table.

Hopefully this should get you started.

Comment: I should understand database concepts instead of solving problems.
Thanks for nice bit of information.